# Is there an efficient way to find minimum xor value between a key and elements of a list?

Tags: python, binary-search, xor

Assume that I have a list of 10 thousand random numbers chosen in this way:

`random_num = list(np.random.choice(2**16, 10000, replace=False))`

Now, I have a key in the same range (e.g., 1024), and I need to find 10 numbers from the sorted list that have minimum value with the key based on the `xor` distance:

`xor_dist = key ^ random_num[i]`

Any suggestion?

I tried to `sort` the `random_num` list and then find the `xor` distance. Because of the `xor` nature, it doesn't work for all keys.

Also, I was thinking to use `banary search` to find the key in the list and then check with the neighbors, but again, it doesn't make the correct result for all keys and depends on where the key is in the range.

Comment: Sorting should work -- with an appropriate choice for the optional `key` argument. What did you try? Binary search doesn't sound very promising. For one thing -- binary search assumes that the list is already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is overkill, because it sorts *all* the numbers in O(n lg n) time, but you don't care about the ordering of 9,990 of the elements.

Instead, use the `heapq` module to build a heap (in O(n) time) from which you can extract the 10 smallest in O(lg n) time.

```
import numpy as np
import heapq

random_num = np.random.choice(2**16, 10000, replace=False)
q = [(x ^ 1024, x) for x in random_num]
heapq.heapify(q)
result = [v for _, v in heapq.nsmallest(10, q)]
```

Comment: A `heapq` in an excellent idea

Answer (score 0):

`sort` will work with the right `key` parameter:

```
import random

random_num = random.choices(range(2**16), k = 10000)
my_key = 1024
random_num.sort(key = lambda x: x^my_key)
print(random_num[:10])
```

Typical output:

```
[1030, 1037, 1042, 1057, 1068, 1077, 1088, 1090, 1108, 1109]
```